# R.java was modified manually?

Tags: android, r.java-file

while updating code I got this error ?

> R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

any one have idea about it?

Comment: If you give wrong naming convention for images in drawable then you will face this problem or if you give package name wrongly ..Specify when you got this problem..

Comment: See if your packages include R.java file. If so then remove it. Just incase clean-built do not works.

Comment: It solved, project required cleanup...that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't worry while updating you code you have modified a R.java so that it will show an error like that , please clean your project and restart the eclipse once may be it will fix the problem.